# Include gem's assets in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, assets

I've created a gem (not engine) that has some js files in it:

```
lib/assets/javascripts/mygem.js
```

In my application, I want to include this js into application.js:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/application.js

// require mygem  # DOESN'T WORK
```

This doesn't work.

Is it possible to include assets from gems? Or I should write a generator for a gem which will copy all assets from gem into application assets folder.

Answer (score 5):

Add Engine class to the gem and require it in gem:

```
# lib/mygem/rails/engine.rb
module Mygem
  module Rails
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine

    end
  end
end
```

```
# lib/mygem.rb:
module Mygem
  require 'mygem/rails/engine'

end
```

Now assets from the gem are available in application:

Gemfile:

```
 gem 'mygem'
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require mygem
```

Read about adding Assets to Your Gems:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#adding-assets-to-your-gems